# How to properly position additional subnav in Twitter's Bootstrap?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I've created my own `.subnav-fixed` (like in Twitter's Bootstrap docs, [css](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/css/docs.css)):

```
@media (min-width: 980px) {
  .subnav-fixed {
    background-image: url(pic146x120.png);
    height: 146px;
    width: 120px;    
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 1020; /* 10 less than .navbar-fixed to prevent any overlap */
  }
}
```

and I try to position that in the same way as other elements are positioned:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="navbar-inner">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row offset1 span6">
        <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">

          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </a>
        <a class="brand" href="index.html">Project</a>
        <div class="nav-collapse">
          <ul class="nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="subnav-fixed offset1 span6">
      test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test 
    </div> 
  </div>
</div>
```

With such code (`offset1 span6`) I expect that my `.subnav-fixed` would be at the same position from the left, where brand is. But actually it is not so - [demo](http://jsbin.com/azirid/6).

Comment: Where exactly are you looking to position your `subnav-fixed` div?

Comment: @AndresIlich, OK, in the question above I've used simplified approach - to have brand Project and this `.subnav-fixed` left aligned. But the final target position is to have it after `.well`. Since `.well` there has `offset1 span7`, I think that I should use `offset8 span2` for my `.subnav-fixed` - http://jsbin.com/azirid/9, but it doesn't work as expected.

Comment: The `position:fixed` attribute removes the element from the natural flow of the document, thus all of the placement classes from the bootstrap will not work as expected at all. So, you have to compensate for that by fixing the div manually using its `top, left, bottom, right` attributes properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clarifications are here - https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/issues/1994